# Plot top 10 verse all other values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a set of information and I want to grab the TOP 10 values verse the everything else. To elaborate I want to add all the values that are not in the TOP 10 together and add them to say a pie chart labeled as "others" along with the top 10. Currently I have the following code where X is my dataframe:

```
temp = X.SOME_IDENTIFIER.value_counts()
temp.head(10).plot(kind='pie')
```

This gets me a pie chart of just the top ten but I do not wish to discard all the other values from the dataframe. I want to add them as an eleventh variable on the chart but am not sure how to do this. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post an example or make what you want clearer? What is this "information" and in what format does it come?

Comment: Sure, let me try to explain better.

I have a dataframe and one of the columns is a name so it is string type. Most of these names appear multiple times (several thousand) and others appear much less. For the ten names that appear the most I want to display them in the pie chart as individual names. For all the other names that are not in the top ten frequencies I want to combine their number of occurences together under say the name "other". Then I can plot this "other group" in the same bar chart as the top ten. Sort of like a way to see how much the top ten occur compared to everyone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign the results to a new dataframe (temp2), and then insert a new record that sums any remaining items in the list.  It also identifies the number of unique items remaining.

```
temp = X.SOME_IDENTIFIER.value_counts()
temp2 = temp.head(10)
if len(temp) > 10:
    temp2['remaining {0} items'.format(len(temp) - 10)] = sum(temp[10:])
temp2.plot(kind='pie')
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, your solution ended up working after I told pandas to treat the column as a string not an integer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Using the following for temp, it worked for me.  temp = pd.Series(np.random.random_integers(0, 20, 50)).value_counts()

Comment: Be careful with `sum(temp[10:])`.  If there are NAN values, the proposed formula will result in NAN.  Since we are using pandas here, perhaps a better solution would be `temp[10:].sum()`.

Comment: How can one get `NaN` from `value_counts()`?

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas:

```
# Sort the DataFrame in descending order; will create a Series
s_temp = X.SOME_IDENTIFIER.sort_values(ascending=False)

# Count how many rows are not in the top ten
not_top_ten = len(s_temp) - 10
    
# Sum the values not in the top ten
not_top_ten_sum = s_temp.tail(not_top_ten).sum()

# Get the top ten values
s_top = s_temp.head(10)

# Append the sum of not-top-ten values to the Series
s_top[10] = not_top_ten_sum

# Plot pie chart
_ = s_top.plot.pie()

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I approached to the problem:

```
temp = X.SOME_IDENTIFIER.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
df=pd.DataFrame({'XX':temp.index,'Y':temp.values})
df=df.append({'XX'='Other','Y'=X.SOME_IDENTIFIER.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[10:].sum()})
df.set_index('XX').plot(kind='pie',y='Y')
```

Explanation----> I stored the top 10 values in a dataframe and manually calculated the sum of the rest of the values from the series and appended the result in the dataframe with the name Other and plotted the piechart for that dataframe.
You will get the result hopefully.